# Drupal 7 Wrong Timestamp showing up in a custom view instead of what is there in the database table

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have a view created in a drupal 7 to display the data fields from a table in the database and one of the fields is date_entered which is a timestamp. But the data in the timestamp field shows up as same for each record as "   1969/12/31 - 19:33" instead of what's there in the table. 
I have tried changing the timestamp format and applying a patch to fix the issue but nothing seems to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a work around, i created a hidden field using date module and used the default site format to populate the hidden field and used the array while doing the submit db insert which in turn populates the data base table with the current date of submission and used that date field in the view to display the date instead of the complete timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Do u use the date module? It solves all date and timestamp issues.

Comment: It is just a view which displays the fields from the database tables and i use the Data module to create this view. @u2tope